# Half Lat/Long Delta with No Extension Necessary

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit, mkmapview

I'm attempting to consolidate what I currently have as an `extension` into my `struct MapView`.

```
 extension MKCoordinateRegion {

    var boundingBoxCoordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] {
        let halfLatDelta = self.span.latitudeDelta / 2
        let halfLngDelta = self.span.longitudeDelta / 2
```

Comment: Provided code snapshot is not compilable and it is not clear what you try to achieve. Would you show more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly but I think the problem is here: `self.span` in `MKCoordinateRegion` extension.

```
extension MKCoordinateRegion {

    static let latitudeDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 1
    static let longitudeDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 1

        var boundingBoxCoordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] {
            let halfLatDelta = MKCoordinateRegion.latitudeDelta / 2
            let halfLngDelta = MKCoordinateRegion.longitudeDelta / 2
            .....
    }
}
```

If you need to declare them as private static property, add `private` keyword after `static`.

Two Swift `extension` rules to mention here:

1. can't declare stored property. compiler error: *Extensions must not contain stored properties*
2. can't declare class property. compiler error: *Class properties are only allowed within classes; use 'static' to declare a static property* (like I used in answer code block)

Comment: Is there a way to get my halves of the delta lat/longs without adding an extension?

Comment: If you are going to use them more than once, adding them into extension is a better way than copy and paste codes all over the project, think as Object Oriented.